# Windowservice error

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

Hi i made some changes in windowservice coding side(some class files related to that),,means i did coding to fetch version value from registry,,After stopping the service i copied the exe from
the application side which was 72 Kb to installerpath side which was 74 Kb as fresh when installed from Installershield.So here 74kb old one is replaced with
72 kb,.But now the problem i am getting is this error

---

### Services

**Could not start the  Monitor service on Local Computer.
Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.**

I googled for this error ,,some forums telling to install fresh framework copy.I did that changes but still getting error,and more over my coding part is 
correct

Can any one suggests any solutions .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i got the mistake,,What actually i was doing is i am copying DLL created in the debug mode  and copying into the Installer path..Actually what i need is i have to copy DLL obtained from the release mode and copy into the installer side

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is to check if the user running the service has permissions to access the registry. Also often you can find more detail in EventViewer.

Otherwise it means that your service takes too long to initialize, please take a look at my old question: [What is the timeout for starting a windows service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160295/what-is-the-timeout-for-starting-a-windows-service)

Answer (score 0):

Services have (if my memory serves me) 30 seconds to reply to a control request (thats start/stop etc).

You should check the code in the `OnStart` method implemented in your service to ensure that nothing is taking a long time. If you do have some long-running task that must occur as your service starts you should start this work on its own thread.