# What is the Start and Stop timeouts for a Windows Service?

Tags: windows-services, windows-server

I am looking for documentation that defines the default timeouts for both *Start* and *Stop* of a Windows Service. I am aware of a [similar asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1160295/700926) but it only covers how to extend the Start timeout - not what the actual values are. Further, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13454054/700926) asks about the Stop timeout, but the answers are not backed by any documentation and seems to be focused on the timeout Windows gives services to stop at OS shutdown.

From [this serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/q/111045/160894) and [this Microsoft KB-article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/922918) it can be derived that the Start timeout is most likely 30 seconds, but I am amazed I cannot find anything that documents what the exact values are. Further, the Stop timeout is not mentioned.

I have been searching for this for a while, but without any luck.

References to official documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is 30 seconds on all machines, unless the registry was hacked.  Based on the average amount of time that a grumpy overworked system admin with a bad attitude is willing to tap his foot before blowing his top.  The kind of person you never want to tick off, never make it take more than a couple of seconds at most.  Ten billion processor instructions is enough for everybody.  Please use this site for programming questions, you can only get "official" documentation from Microsoft.

Comment: Note also that the 30 second start timeout only applies until the service calls StartServiceCtrlDispatcher().  Once that has been called, no timeout is enforced.  Since that's the very first thing the service executable is supposed to do, thirty seconds ought to be plenty.  *One* second ought to be plenty.  Move all your initialization to *after* that call and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen any official documentation on the value, but the message in the windows event viewer shows the timeout.

A timeout (30000 milliseconds) was reached while waiting for a transaction response from the ImperoServiceStarter service.

That came from a service stop, but the start error is the same. I believe all service operations use the same value, but again, I can find no documentation to show this.